# select Index Change on javaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some problem: I have Rad Combo Box that calls User Types and once I populate all the info I want to create JS function everytime the user click on something else in the Rad Combo Box it will pop up some message
I know that I need to use The OnSelectedIndexChange event but maybe I'm using it on the wrong way please help me

This is my Code: JS

```
  function OnSelectedIndexChange(sender,args) {
    var retValRCB = false
    var l_UserType = $find("<%=rcbUserType.ClientID %>");
    var l_UserTypeInd = l_UserType.get_selectedIndex();

    if (!(l_UserTypeInd == null))
        retValRCB = true;
    else {
        alert("Please select rule type");
        retValRCB = false;
    }
    return retValRCB;
 }
```

This is My Code in Asp:

User Type:
                
                
                    ID="rcbUserType"  OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChange" EmptyMessage="Select User Type" runat="server">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function OnSelectedIndexChange(sender, args) {
    var l_UserType = $find("ctl00_MainContent_rcbUserType");
    var l_UserTypeInd = l_UserType.get_selectedIndex();

    if (!(l_UserTypeInd == null)){
        alert((l_UserTypeInd+1)+" has been selected");
        }
 }
```